# Cannot sign in with google app engine plugin

Tags: google-app-engine

When trying to sign in using the button in the lower left corner of the screen, I am unable to do so because it needs a verification code. However, I am not offered the chance to receive one, it only brings me directly to the "allow this application page." The exact error in the log is

`Could not sign in. Make sure that you entered the correct verification code.`

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you have two-factor authentication enabled on your Google account?

Comment: What button in the lower left corner of the screen? Plugin to what?

Comment: RileyLark No, I do not.

NickJohnson The lower left corner of eclipse, and the plugin that google provides for google app engine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, resolved by changing network settings as follows:

In Eclipse:
Preferences > General > Network Connections

- Set Active Provider to Manual
- Under Proxy entries, edit the HTTPS proxy, adding host and port info
- Check "Requires authentication" and add your network ID and password

Comment: Stack Overflow posts are not threads; answers are always welcome, no matter how old the question is! :-)

Comment: I am getting this problem too. I don't have a network ID and password and I am not using a proxy. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Mac OS X.
However, after upgrading my JDK from 1.6 to 1.7 my problems disappeared.(Note: JDK not JRE)

The default java on Mac 10.x is Java SE 6 and you can't uninstall it. You can add Java 1.7 or higher and your system should automatically pick up the later version -you can check from the terminal with

> $java -version